# Module not found Error: Can't resolve '@swc/core' and 'esbuild'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack, esbuild

Error Log

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@swc/core' in '/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'
  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@swc/core' in '/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2016:28
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:798:13
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:270:22
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:434:22
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:11
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:670:25
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:855:8
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:975:5
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6883:13
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:958:45
      at finishWithoutResolve (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:312:11)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:386:15
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:16:12
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/AliasPlugin.js:125:14
      at next (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:14:3)
      at forEachBail (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:24:9)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/AliasPlugin.js:51:5
      at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:8:1)
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:41:15
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esbuild' in '/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'
  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esbuild' in '/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2016:28
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:798:13
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:270:22
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:434:22
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:11
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:670:25
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:855:8
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:975:5
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6883:13
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:958:45
      at finishWithoutResolve (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:312:11)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:386:15
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:16:12
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/AliasPlugin.js:125:14
      at next (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:14:3)
      at forEachBail (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:24:9)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/AliasPlugin.js:51:5
      at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:8:1)
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:435:5
      at eval (eval at create (/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
      at /Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:41:15
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

  - Compilation.js:2016
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2016:28

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:798
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:798:13


  - NormalModuleFactory.js:270
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:270:22


  - NormalModuleFactory.js:434
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:434:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:116
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:11

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:670
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:670:25

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:855
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:855:8

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:975
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:975:5

  - async.js:6883
    [clarity-app]/[neo-async]/async.js:6883:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:958
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:958:45

  - Resolver.js:312 finishWithoutResolve
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:312:11

  - Resolver.js:386
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:386:15

  - Resolver.js:435
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:435:5


  - Resolver.js:435
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:435:5


  - DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43

  - Resolver.js:435
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:435:5


  - forEachBail.js:16
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/forEachBail.js:16:12

  - AliasPlugin.js:125
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/AliasPlugin.js:125:14

  - forEachBail.js:14 next
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/forEachBail.js:14:3

  - forEachBail.js:24 forEachBail
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/forEachBail.js:24:9

  - AliasPlugin.js:51
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/AliasPlugin.js:51:5



  - Resolver.js:435
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:435:5


  - Resolver.js:435
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:435:5


  - Resolver.js:435
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:435:5


  - DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43

  - Resolver.js:435
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:435:5


  - Resolver.js:435
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:435:5


  - DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:41
    [clarity-app]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:41:15

  - task_queues:82 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21

  - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esbuild' in '/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

  - ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esbuild' in '/Users/monish/code/my-app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

  - Compilation.js:2016
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2016:28

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:798
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:798:13


  - NormalModuleFactory.js:270
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:270:22


  - NormalModuleFactory.js:434
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:434:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:116
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:11

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:670
    [clarity-app]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:670:25



2 ERRORS in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 3 errors and 9 warnings in 7431 ms
```

My package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production node build/build.js",
    "staging": "NODE_ENV=staging node build/staging.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.json,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.1",
    "@websanova/vue-auth": "^2.21.11-beta",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "compare-versions": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.26.1",
    "dinero.js": "^1.4.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "v-autocomplete": "^1.8.2",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.0-rc.33",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.8",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-crono": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.16",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-json-excel": "^0.2.98",
    "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.10",
    "vue-numeric": "^2.3.0",
    "vue-observe-visibility": "^0.4.3",
    "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.5",
    "vue-quill": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-rangedate-picker": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-select": "^2.5.1",
    "vue-spinner": "^1.0.3",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.2",
    "vuejs-paginator": "^2.0.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.8.1",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "chromedriver": "^107.0.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.4.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-formatter-friendly": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.7.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.0",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "ora": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "semver": "^5.4.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.5",
    "uglify-js": "^3.17.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.3.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

```js
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')

// add hot-reload related code to entry chunks
Object.keys(baseWebpackConfig.entry).forEach(function (name) {
  baseWebpackConfig.entry[name] = ['./build/dev-client'].concat(baseWebpackConfig.entry[name])
})

// Todo: Remove
process.traceDeprecation = true

module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': config.dev.env
    }),
    // https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#installation--usage
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
      {
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.dev.html',
      inject: true,
      serviceWorkerLoader: `<script>${fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,
        './service-worker-dev.js'), 'utf-8')}</script>`
      }
    ),
    new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
  ]
})
```

I'm not sure why @swc/core is need. But I tried installing it, which increases errors. I'm not finding a reason why esbuild is need with webpack?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend that you delete your `node_modules` and install everything back with yarn or PNPM. It will be more verbose and may provide better feedback/errors as of why that one needs those dependencies or throw some errors at least.

Comment: @kissu Thanks for your response. I have tried deleting node_modules. The output is the same. I'm using yarn. I'm able to install dependencies, but when I run the app, it throws error

Comment: Maybe try that one: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/why/ There should be a dependency deep somewhere needing `@swc/core` for some reason.

Comment: webpack has a dependency terser-webpack-plugin, terser-webpack-plugin has a optional dependency @swc/core esbuild https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/blob/master/package.json

Comment: You got your answer!

Comment: Did you enable `swc` or `esbuild` in the webpack config?
Could you share the webpack config file?

Comment: @cwillinx I haven't enable swc or esbuild. Adding part of webpack config in question

Comment: @kissu I'm not able to understand why this error is displayed, & it says dependency is missing of package. I tried searching online didn't get any help